# Java HotSpot(TM) Client sharing vs no sharing

Tags: java

I was looking at my JDK installations and I saw a difference between two installations:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

vs

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And I was wondering what the difference between the `sharing` and `not sharing` state is.

I couldn't find a good answer other than "a speed difference", but no explanations why/what this is about.

Comment: [Class Data Sharing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called `Class Data Sharing`, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html); *this only works* for a `Client VM`.

Basically it is a way to speed-up the start-up time of the VM - the parsed classes are stored in a file and when the VM starts, it just reads that file (with already compiled classes), it also can be shared with other running VMs.

The `shared` build will contain a file `jre\bin\client\classes.jsa` and the other one will not.

Since java-8 you can add your own classes to that file - if I remember correctly and the native code (not the byte code) will be there for grabs.

I have not used Client VM's with this support - just read about it.

Comment: I think, this information, i.e. that it only works for client JVMs, is hopelessly outdated. Note that even this page itself says, “on Microsoft Windows platforms [it is located] in `jre/bin/[client or server]/classes.jsa`”. If I try to use `-Xshare:on -server` (mind that `-Xshare:on` *requires* CDA and will fail if not supported), I get no errors. Well, there was no need to specify `-server`, actually, as there is no client JVM for 64 bit architectures…